# Add group id by hiveql

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table in a hadoop that has 2 columns containing string data.

So, for a table that looks like this:

```
+---------+------+
|   v1    | v2   |
+---------+------+
|    1    | 2    |
|    1    | 3    |
|    2    | 3    |
|    4    | 5    |
|    6    | 7    |
+---------+------+
```

Now, I want to add group id to each rows. Regardless of columns Values belong to, rows which have same values get same group id.

So, like below.

```
+---------+------+------+
|   v1    | v2   | gid  |
+---------+------+------+
|    1    | 2    | 1    |
|    1    | 3    | 1    |
|    2    | 3    | 1    |
|    4    | 5    | 2    |
|    6    | 7    | 3    |
+---------+------+------+
```

How can I write to get that by hiveql?

Comment: *"Now, I want to add group id to each rows. Regardless of columns Values belong to, rows which have same values get same group id."*  No idea it is still not clear what you mean as the expected results does not seam to follow -> *"rows which have same values get same group id."*..

Comment: I'm sorry for my vague explanation. I mean that a row which has same values with other rows' should have get same group id. For example, first row and second row have same number(1), so they have same gid 1. And second row and third row have same number(3), so third row also has gid 1.

Comment: @gogogogogo . . . This is a graph-walking problem.  In SQL this is usually handled using recursive CTEs.  Hive does not (yet) support them.

Comment: Oh my gosh. Okay, thanks for your reply, Gordon. I will search other ways for my problem.

Comment: @gogogogogo Please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general this is graph-walking problem as @GordonLinoff says but if the task can be reduced to that like in your example, with limited columns and having ordering rule (I assumed the order of rows is defined by your columns), the task is quite solvable. See this demo using your dataset, it produces desired result (read comments in the code):

```
with your_data as ( --your data example
select stack (5,
1, 2,
1, 3,
2, 3,
4, 5,
6, 7 
) as (v1,v2)
) --your data example

select v1, v2, --calculate group Id as a running count of new_grp
       count(new_grp) over(order by v1, v2 rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as gid
from
(
select v1, v2, --calculate new_grp flag
       case when ((not array_contains(prev_tuple,v1) and not array_contains(prev_tuple,v2)) or prev_tuple is null) then true end as new_grp
from
(
select v1, v2, lag(tuple) over (order by v1, v2) prev_tuple --get previous values in array, to simplify code a little bit
  from (select v1, v2, array(v1, v2) as tuple from your_data) s
)s
)s;
```

Result:

```
v1      v2      gid
1       2       1
1       3       1
2       3       1
4       5       2
6       7       3
```